# RESTconf Operations with curl

Tags: curl, opendaylight, ietf-restconf

I am trying to do GET, DELETE and PUT operations on a OpenDaylight Database.
On my ubuntu 14.04 with OpenDaylight 3.0.3, I used curl out of the terminal:

GET works pretty well with

```
curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/ModulName:Node
```

PUT also works fine with

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT -d '{"Module":
{"Node":[
   {"type":"value"
   },
   {"type":"value"
   }
  ]
 }
}' http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/Module
```

But I have had a hard time trying to do DELETE operations or reading a single parameter. Is there a way do achieve this with curl?

Comment: You are not supposed to send any body using the DELETE method.

Comment: I should have added my try for the delete operation:curl -u admin:admin -X DELETE http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/ModulName:Node

No body, but didn't work.